# NVIDIA Drivers are not working anymore - only 1 screen is detected, max resolution 800x600

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I'm currently stuck at a problem that I can't solve by myself. Recently, my OBS (Open Broadcast Software) stopped working, so I've decided to test a little bit around to get it fixed.

I've done `update`, `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade` and `-f install` and did several updates, including linux header updates which seem now to make problems.

After a reboot I've only had 1 single desktop for use, and the max resolution was 800x600. Also, my nvidia X Server-Window hasn't any more the settings that were available before (only 2 options now, both useless).

I've purged all nvidia-packets an reinstalled nvidia-304 and nvidia-352 (I wasn't sure which one I need, since I have a GTX 780 - or 740, not sure right now). Both didn't worked.

So basically, in short, here's my problem:

- having a GTX 7xx Graphic Card
- Using Ubuntu 14.04
- recently updated linux headers trough `apt-get dist-upgrade`
- now having bugs with the graphic engine.

How can I fix this, and how can I get appropriate Drivers back to working?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all currently installed NVIDIA software.
Select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest stable drivers for GTX 7 series cards.
Select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
sudo reboot
```

Note : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.
After the NVIDIA drivers are installed adding the boot parameter is not necessary anymore.
When you want to install the latest official drivers, replace `nvidia-367` with `nvidia-370`.

Comment: It keeps telling me that nouveau.modeset cannot be found. What did I do wrong here? I eventually blocked nouveau in the blacklist before. Not really sure if I undid this change..

Comment: This site is telling me that specific nvidia-versions are needed for specific graphic cards: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/nvidia/nvidia/

Comment: @Max : Undo the settings you made before and follow exactly the description ... this method worked in most of all cases ... and the article you mentioned somehow is a bit misleading, it tells you which drivers are available in the default repositories. In case that you still receive an error - try it without adding the boot parameter. Most important is to perform the complete drivers installation from the virtual console.

Comment: Okay, thanks. In dpkg I still have a lot of nvidia bundles, all with <UNKOWN>. Shall I worry about those?

Comment: @Max : After completely purging the old NVIDIA drivers / software and rebooting to perform the new drivers installation, everything should be correct ... now please try it out and report back the results. :)

Comment: Your solution hasn't worked. :/ Im still having the problems. Did it tree times to be sure I did nothing wrong (install, reboot, uninstall, reboot, install reboot, ...). In additional drivers I have `NVIDIA binary driver - version 370.28 of nvidia-370 get used (open source)` and a lot of different other versions.

Comment: @Max : Then something else must have gone completely wrong, maybe a broken kernel installation ?

Comment: I updated to 16.04 and trashed the old installation. Nvidia seems to have huge bugs with newer linux headers, or vice versa. Just for your information.

Comment: @Max : Thanks for your feedback ! Well you know, I am using ubuntu since 2007 on different machines, two of them with NVIDIA graphics. Right now I am on 16.10 with kernel 4.8 - I ran 16.04 with kernel 4.4 for six months and never experienced any problem. All depends on a proper setup : I always perform clean installations and never upgrade a system. The first thing I do after the basic system installation is to install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers. Maybe that makes the difference - I wish you good luck to getting your issues sorted out. You may want to consider starting over from scratch ?

Comment: I've started new from scratch when I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 over my now old Ubuntu 14.04. I didn't installed any nvidia drivers, and switched from nouveau to closed-source, tested 361 drivers, rebooted -> Error. Am not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @Max : Eventually it is possible that you are facing a graphics adapter hardware failure, otherwise I have no explanation for what's going on here. One last idea : Please reinstall 16.04 once again, but before you start, format the target partition with ext4 file system to clean everything that was installed. You can use GParted for this - it is included in the installation media. When the basic installation is finished, boot the system and install the NVIDIA drivers from a virtual terminal and reboot afterwards. Hope that works ! :)

Comment: Would you mind posting that solution stepwise to http://askubuntu.com/questions/843866/ubuntu-16-04-switching-from-nouveau-to-closed-source-driver-after-luks-auth-p? That would help others in the future! :)

Comment: @Max : When it really does work, of course I can post this as an answer to your other question, but first you have to try it out - otherwise it wouldn't make much sense. Here you can find comprehensive information on [How to prepare a disk ...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu/743098#743098) including a presentation -> [Prepare the disk for the installation ...](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1HEBkP-nAPAaouS-DzLsFldL7vH6PMmUIt_wtBQXUeag/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciated, as a beginner, this is the best help I can ask for. :)

Comment: @Max : You're welcome ! Let's hope that it's not a hardware issue and we can get it done. Prepare the disk and install ubuntu as shown in the slides, then install the drivers ... once finished, please report back ... :)

Comment: I just solved it. Installing graphic-drivers-ppa and stick to `nvidia-370` solved my problem. What could I ask for more, right now? :)

Comment: Sure thing. I now need t omove over the recovery header in order to get it loading, but thats fine for me to be honest... :')