# Ubuntu 16.04 - switching from nouveau to closed source driver, after LUKS auth purple screen

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, luks

When I change my nvidia graphic card drivers from nouveau to the closed source, tested driver, everything works fine.

Right after a reboot I do not get past the LUKS auth screen. The window stays purple. TTYs are not loaded yet, and I cannot look at the terminal.

What should I do now to return to normal usage of Ubuntu WITH nvidia drivers, not nouveau?

Answer (score 0):

This has helped:

Installing nvidia-370 seems to fix a lot, but theres a bug. This solution worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/843534/600016

Now I just need to use the recovery image and just straight resume everytime, otherwise it'll stop loading at the `initial ramdisk`-bootloader.